# ibaction to switch text of two labels

Tags: ios, button, text, label

I have two labels: oneLabel and twoLabel. Let's say oneLabel displays '1' and twoLabel displays '2'. I'm trying to create a button that when pressed will switch the text between the labels. I'm trying:

```
- (IBAction)switchButton:(id)sender {
    self.oneLabel.text = self.twoLabel.text;
    self.twoLabel.text = self.oneLabel.text;
}
```

The code switches twoLabel text to oneLabel, but not oneLabel text to twoLabel. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because after copying twoLabel's text to oneLabel; oneLable's text has twoLabel's text and when you try to copy the text from one to two ,one has two's content and  that content only is copied to two so no change is seen in twoLable. Use breakpoints and check.Try

```
NSString *temp = self.oneLable.text;
self.oneLable.text= self.twoLable.text;
self.twoLable.text= temp;
```

Comment: last line should not contain extra self, it should be like - `self.twoLable.text= temp;`

Answer (score 0):

Set 2 temporary strings>
      NSString *myText1Str, *myText2Str;

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder]; //to hide the keyboard
[self setString]; //calling the method when u hit enter or return
return YES;
```

}

```
-(void)setString{ //this method sets the current string values from the textfield
   myText1Str = self.oneLabel.text;
   myText1Str = self.twoLabel.text;
}


-(IBAction)switchButton :(id)sender{ //swaps the texts
self.oneLabel.text = myText2Str;
self.oneLabel.text = myText1Str;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
     NSString *str=lbl1.text;
     NSString *str1=lbl2.text;

     lbl1.text=str1;
     lbl2.text=str;

}
```